# How do I configure firebase code on my app

Tags: swift, firebase

this is my error

Thread 1: "`FirebaseApp.configure()` could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from [https://console.firebase.google.com/."](https://console.firebase.google.com/.%22)

this is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase


@main
struct Tour__20_Twitter_cloneApp: App {
  @StateObject var viewModel  = AuthViewModel()
    init() {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    }
    
    
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView  {
              ContentView()
            }
            .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you downloaded a GoogleService-Info.plist from https://console.firebase.google.com ?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit. Did you follow step 3 from this documentation on adding the Firebase config file to you app? https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#add-config-file I linked a few questions where this was covered before, but you can find more when you [search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=FirebaseApp.configure()+could+not+find+a+valid+GoogleService-Info.plist+in+your+project).